# ios: workflow app, is there a way to open several new tabs?

Tags: ios, automation

I use the workflow ios app and I have created a workflow that opens a certain url once. This works fine and it opens this one url in a new tab. However, if I set this to repeat x amount of times it opens all urls in the same tab. (It could also be that the app "refuses" to repeat the command, hard to tell the difference. The central point is that I can only get one new tab, not more.)

The URL I use is `https://pinboard.in/random/?type=unread` which is a link that redirects to the URL of a random unread item in the bookmarking service pinboard.

The actions I use now are:

```
URL [$my_url]
Open URLs
```

With repeat it is:

```
URL $my_url]
Open URLs
Repeat 5
```

Is there some way to open one or more URLs in separate tabs with one workflow app workflow?

Comment: Are you trying to open the same URL multiple times or are they different?

Comment: it's the same URL, but it redirects to a random page from a list

Comment: Can you give us some example URLs, I think the issue here is a Safari 'feature'. Depending on the URL, if Safari thinks it's the same page it has already open, it will reload that tab when opening it through a external link for example.

Comment: this is the URL, it opens a random URL saved in the bookmarking service pinboard: https://pinboard.in/random/?type=unread

Comment: Okay well, if I copy it to Textedit and open it a few times it opens new tabs in Safari, so the issue does seem to be with workflow afterall..

Comment: hm, this is an ios app

Answer (score 1):

Open URLs action supports multiple URL input. Try putting the one URL in a List action, with however many list entries you need, and passing that into Open URLs. Should work